# The position of the object changed by the JS function?

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, css-position

I have a problem, before adding the JS, just with the HTML and CSS, the two images overlapped well but since I added this function to my code, the concerned image (icon-cart-white) is no longer arranged in the same position and I do not know what to change so that it returns to normal, if you know how to fix this problem I would be very grateful. Thank you

[This is before i add the JS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahy3c.png)

[This is after i add the JS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llehy.png)

```
HTML (before the JS) :

<img class="calebasse-icon-cart-white" src="calebasse-white" alt ="white-icon-cart"> 
<img class="calebasse-icon-cart-black" src="calebasse-black" alt ="black-icon-cart">


HTML (with the JS) :

<iconcart id="iconcart">
    <img class="calebasse-icon-cart-white" src="calebasse-white" alt ="white-icon-cart"> 
</iconcart>

<img class="calebasse-icon-cart-black" src="calebasse-black" alt ="black-icon-cart">
```

```
CSS :

.calebasse-icon-cart-white {
  position: absolute;
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.calebasse-icon-cart-black {
  position: absolute;
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```
JS :

let iconcart = document.getElementById('iconcart');

document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {

    let scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;

    if (scrollPosition <= 50) {
        iconcart.style.opacity = 1 - scrollPosition / 50;
    } else {
        iconcart.style.opacity = 0;
    }
});
```

I tried to change the `position: absolute;` to `position: relative;` to solve the problem but it wasn't better, i thought the problem was the CSS but in fact in not really sure, it can also be the JS.

Comment: could it be that the `iconcart` element is creating some extra element that causes the issue? You should inspect the element and see what's happening.  Otherwise you will need to create a [mcve] to demonstrate the issue as any answers we provide will only be a guess with the code you have supplied

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
Instead of creating  tag i just put the id in the  tag and it worked, I don't really know why but it's fine for me. Thank you Pete for helping me with the Minimal, reproducible example article.